# How to apply style to element before it loads

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events

Particularly I am interested in images and background images. The style is injected with a CSS class into the page from a chrome extension. The class that is applied to every element before the page is loaded with `DOMContentLoaded` event listener, smth like that:

```
   $(document).ready(insertClass)
```

Eventhough, according to the description of `DOMContentLoaded` the function should run before the element is loaded, I still have a visual of images without the style applied for a split second, meaning that style is applied after the image is rendered. Is there a way to apply style before the image is rendered?

Comment: do you load the images with javascript or are they statically included in the html?

Comment: @CisumInas Images are loaded with the page which I have no control of since I inject style with the chrome extension. Therefore, it could be both.